# Convergence using Laplace transform

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the sequence $(Y_n)_{n\ge 1}$ of iid and integrable random variables, which are not almost surely constant.

Let $\delta>0$ and for all $\lambda\in(-\delta,\delta)$ it holds $$L(\lambda):=E[e^{\lambda Y_1}]<\infty$$

Define $$\psi:(-\delta,\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad\psi(\lambda):=\log(L(\lambda))$$

For $n\ge 0$ define
$$X_n^\lambda:=e^{\lambda\sum_{i=1}^nY_i-n\psi(\lambda)}$$

I was able to show, that $\psi$ is strictly convex on $(-\delta,\delta)$ by using the inequality of Cauchy-Schwarz and that $e^{\frac{\lambda_1}{2}Y_1}$ and $e^{\frac{\lambda_2}{2}Y_1}$ are linear independent for $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$. snarksi contributed a nice answer how to show that $E[\sqrt{X_n^\lambda}]\rightarrow 0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

At last I want to show that $X_n^\lambda\rightarrow 0$ almost surely for $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $\lambda\ne 0$.

**Guess:** This looks like I need to use the strong law of large numbers, but I am not sure about this yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in bringing in the factor of 2. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
E[ (X_n^\lambda)^{1/2} ] &= E[e^{\frac{1}{2}(\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - n \psi(\lambda))}] \\
&= E[e^{\frac{\lambda}{2}Y_1}]^n e^{-\frac{n}{2} \psi(\lambda)} \\
&=e^{n \psi(\lambda/2) - n\psi(\lambda)/2}.
\end{align*}
So it suffices to show that $\psi(\lambda/2) - \psi(\lambda)/2 < 0$, as then the argument of the exponential is negative and you can send $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Since the functions are not almost surely constant, the variance is positive and $\psi''(0) > 0$. The function $\psi$ is also smooth on $(-\delta, \delta)$, and $\psi(0) = 0$. We have, for sufficiently small $\lambda > 0$,
\begin{align*}
\psi(\lambda/2) - \psi(\lambda)/2 &= \psi(0) + \frac{\lambda}{2} \psi'(0) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\lambda^2}{4} \psi''(0) \\
&-\frac{1}{2}(\psi(0) + \lambda \psi'(0) + \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 \psi''(0))+O(\lambda^3) \\
&= -\frac{\lambda^2}{8}\psi''(0)+O(\lambda^3).
\end{align*}
Choosing $\lambda > 0$ sufficiently small will guarantee that the expression is negative.

Edit: previous argument was not correct, strict convexity does not guarantee $\psi''(0) > 0$.

Comment: Oh, yes, the 2 is missing. But wow, this is a really nice argument. I am curious about finding out more about cumulants. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hm, yes, as you have written now, I wanted to mention, that one probably needs now that the functions are not almost surely constant, but how does this imply $\psi''(0)>0$?

Comment: I'll leave that to you: what is $\psi''(0)$ equal to?

Comment: $\psi''(0)=Var[Y_1]$

Comment: Ok, now there is a technical question left. What does not almost surely constant mean? Because of course I can have $Y_1=E[Y_1]$ on a non $P$-zerosubset and $Y_1=0$ on the complement. This is not a constant function, but still $Var[Y_1]=0$.

Comment: So maybe one should be more precise by saying not almost surely accepting values $E[Y_1]$ or $0$?

Comment: The space $L^1$ is a space of equivalence classes, where functions which differ only on a null set are identified. The function which is equal to $E[Y_1]$ except on a null set is identified with a constant function and referred to as a constant function.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about both $supp(Y_1)$ and $supp(Y_1)^c$ are not null subsets. Then take $Y_1=E[Y_1]$ on $supp(Y_1)$ and $Y_1=0$ on $supp(Y_1)^c$. But then $Var[Y_1]=E[Y_1-E[Y_1]]^2=E[Y_1]^2\cdot P[supp(Y_1)^c]^2$

Comment: In the last formula it is only $P[supp(Y_1)^c]$, not squared. Also, of course, $Var[Y_1]=E[(Y_1-E[Y_1])^2]$.